# Pressure Inverting Reflection of a Sound Wave

Tags: waves, acoustics

How would the frequency and energy of a pressure inverted sound wave compare to the frequency and energy of the original sound? Would it sound any different?

Comment: Sound waves do not invert when reflecting off of "hard" surfaces/boundaries.  Meaning, the high density/pressure pulse of a reflected sound wave is the same as the incident wave, i.e., no phase change.  So I am not sure the title of your question is accurate.  You could change it and just ask whether the ear would respond differently to an inverted (i.e., rarefaction) pressure pulse than a normal pressure pulse.

Answer (score 1):

A sound wave with inverted phase does not sound any different from the original. However it does interact differently with other sound waves so switching a phase of a single wave in a complex sound field would result in an audible change.